# What does the / mean?

Tags: meaning, slash

Looking at forms in financial risk assessment, there is a question 'I'm happy investing a large proportion of my income / capital in a high-risk investment'. Is the '/' here being used as shorthand for '... proportion of either my income or my capital'; does it mean 'either / or' and is there a way to express it without using a '/'? Main concern is whether the / is open to interpretation.

Comment: / refers to: ***and/or***

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the problems surrounding the use of the slash / virgule have been mentioned here before. You're right to be concerned: [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) contains << **Meaning and**
 
The slash sometimes serves as shorthand for _and_, as in:
 
He is enrolling in the JD/MBA program at Harvard. [I'd emphasise the 'combined' sense, often represented by a hyphen, here.]
 
**Meaning or**
 
The slash sometimes serves as shorthand for _or_ ... >> ....

Comment: As Josh61 says, _and/or_ is another not uncommon reading. I use the slash where I'm not altogether sure whether _and_, _or_, or _and/or_ is preferable, and think the reader can profitably explore the possibilities themself. But you need to make sure which way it's being used (by asking for clarification) where consequences could be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html)

> - The slash ( / ), also known as the virgule, has several uses, most of which should be avoided in formal writing.

Meaning ***and***

> - The slash sometimes serves as shorthand for and, as in:
>
>   - He is enrolling in the JD/MBA program at Harvard.

Meaning ***or***

> - The slash sometimes serves as shorthand for or, as in:
>
>   - Each guest must present his/her ticket prior to entry.
>   - Once the new president is elected, he/she will have little time to waste.
>   - The deficit reduction will be achieved by spending cuts ***and/or*** tax increases.

(www.thepunctuationguide.com)

- In the sentence you are showing I think it is used to mean ***and/or***.

Comment: Ironically, your proposed explanation of the slash also includes a slash within it!